# What is the best way to learn .Net Quickbooks development?

Tags: .net, quickbooks

I have recently inherited an desktop application that interact with QuickBooks (QBFC).  I have spent many hours combing through the SDK documentation and watching videos. Now, I would like to take it to the next level, but I am not sure where to find training or certification(s).  Are there any conferences, code boot-camp, certifications, or instructor lead courses? Thanks for helping!

Comment: C# is more popular but you can use the one you want

Comment: Thanks phill652, but I am looking for training in either languages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no bootcamps, prep courses, certifications or any such thing.

QuickBooks is a product belonging to Intuit, and as such it simply has an API which you call to achieve things. Other than reading the doco and talking with other developers in that space there is nothing more than that.